# filter subdocuments where field does not exist

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection of objects where each object contains versions some of which have delete field and would like to filter these which were not deleted or later than the given timestamp.

```
db
.getCollection('test')
.aggregate([
{$project:
 {versions:
  {$filter:
   {input: '$versions',
    as: 'version',
    cond:
    {
        $or: [
        {$gte: ['$$version.delete', 3]},
        {'$$version.delete': {$exists: false}}
        ]
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
])
```

but field name probably can't be used inside filter because I get an error:  invalid operator '$$version.delete'

Any ideas what is the proper syntax of this query?

Comment: Try aggregation comparison operator `{$ifNull:["$$version.delete", false]}}` instead of query comparison operator ( can only be used in match stage) `{'$$version.delete': {$exists: false}}` and also add initial match to limit the documents. `{$match:{
        $or: [
        {'versions.delete':{$gte: 3},
        {'versions.delete': {$exists: false}}
        ]
    }`

Comment: that's going to rule out subdocuments where `delete` exists but is null.

Answer (score 11):

You want to use aggregation syntax for checking type of delete field and comparing it to `missing` which is what `$exists:false` would be:

```
{$eq:[{$type:'$$version.delete'},"missing"]}
```

Comment: This answer is very useful, Thanks buddy

Comment: Only took me 2 hours of googling to find this answer. GBless MongoDB documentation ...